# Rollback Error in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to delete one column, it worked but for the " rollback" it always shows up an error!

> ERROR : parse error: syntax error,unexpected end of file,expectinf function (T_FUNCTION) or const ( T_CONST)

the code :

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class DropBody extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->dropColumn('body');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->mediumText('body');
        });
    }
}
```

.

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from this file? If so, I would first suggest deleting the file and recreating it. Sounds like you've got a curly brace missing somewhere.

Comment: this file was generated automatically after running the migration, I just added those 2 methods!                                                            
the column " body " get removed successfuly but when I rollback it  shows that error in the top...

Comment: Can you check your laravel.log for full error messages? It should include file and line numbers.

Comment: it's resolved guys , thank you everyone , the error was coming from another file

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are writing reverse code, by reverse code i mean to say you have to create table fields in up function and drop columns in down function.

You should try something like this:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
  public function up()
  {
      Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->mediumText('body');
       });
  }

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->dropColumn('body');
    });
}
```

Comment: First , Thank you for the reply
it's not because of that,because if u want to delete a column with the new migration , if you make a rollback u will get back that column again ;)

Comment: Yes , you are right. but it matters in migration file where you adding your pile of code for adding your columns or for rolling them back.